# PHP - String pattern matching

Tags: php, string, pattern-matching

I need to know if there is any way I can do the following using regular expressions (or otherwise) in PHP

> aaBaa BBB -> aa Baa BBB

ie, I want to introduce a space before a capital letter only if a Capital letter occurs before and after a small letter.

The best I could come up with was something like this

```
$string = preg_replace('/(\w+)([A-Z])/U', '\\1 \\2', $string);
```

but that would only give me something like

> aaBaa BBB -> aa Baa B B B

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here: http://rubular.com/r/3xqbuWuiLD

```
([a-z]+)([A-Z]+)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('|([a-z])([A-Z])([a-z])|', '$1 $2$3', $txt);
```

Comment: I thank you for your answer, but I felt @sergei's was better as it taught me how to take care of such things in the future.